# Responsive webpage with Semantic UI and 1rem == 10px trick

Tags: css, angular, responsive-design, semantic-ui, theming

In my project I am using Semantic UI as components library (also with ng2-semantic-ui because it is Angular app). I want my application to be responsive. One way to achieve this goal, which I am using in projects without any CSS frameworks is to:

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%; // This makes 1rem equal to 10px by default, using only rems - easy to code that way 
}
// just a SASS mixin
@include respond(tablet-landscape) { 
    font-size: 56.25%; // on smaller screens I make font size smaller, everything works great
}

@include respond(tablet-portrait) { 
    font-size: 50%; //1 rem = 8px
}
```

Now I would like to use this method with Semantic UI powered project but there is a problem. When I use it user interface elements are getting smaller, so my next step was to tweak default Semantic theme to use bigger relative values. I imagine this way I will have my 1rem == 10px thing and Semantic element will have normal size and will be responsive with my responsive mixins.

```
/*-------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  Base Sizes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
--------------------*/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          


/* This is the single variable that controls them all */                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

@emSize   : 14px;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               


/* The size of page text  */                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
@fontSize : 14px;
```

Base settings seems simple enough. But despite many attempts I can't achieve this behavior. Does anyone can help? Or maybe this is not possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, in the [semantic.css](https://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.css), the `font-size` of the `html` element is explicitly set as below.

```
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

And in order to achieve your requirement, you may override it in your css either by loading it after the semantic.css or by using `!important`. Hope this helps, let me know.